# Extracting a raster from a large list in R

Tags: raster, r

I have some code that returns a raster nested in a large list, I want to extract the raster from the list and save it as a tiff so that I can export it and use it in ArcGIS.

```
my_raster<-raster("/sadabe.tif")

plot(my_raster)

check_landscape(my_raster)

>layer       crs units   class n_classes OK

>1     1 projected     m integer         2  v

# get spatialized lsm
area_patch <- landscapemetrics::spatialize_lsm(my_raster, what = "lsm_p_area")

area_patch

#This returns 

> area_patch

[[1]]

[[1]]$lsm_p_area

class      : RasterLayer 

dimensions : 598, 790, 472420  (nrow, ncol, ncell)

resolution : 33.54191, 33.54191  (x, y)

extent     : 5313077, 5339575, -2247065, -2227007  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

crs        : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs 

source     : memory

names      : value 

values     : 0.112506, 21099.15  (min, max)
```

So I want to get the raster 'lsm_p_area' out of the list and as a stand alone tiff.

rast<-area_patch$lsm_p_area returns as empty

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bit more nesting going in I think.

This is trying to get an element called `lsm_p_area` of a list object called `area_patch`:

```
rast<-area_patch$lsm_p_area
```

But this printout shows that `area_patch` is a list, and the first element (`[[1]]`) *is also a list* with an element called `lsm_p_area`:

```
> area_patch

[[1]]

[[1]]$lsm_p_area
```

So what I think would work is `area_raster <- area_patch[[1]]$lsm_p_area`

and then you can `writeRaster(area_raster,etc...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have different rasters in the main list `area_patch[[i]]lsm_p_area` you can use:

```
output_path <- "C:/folder"
dir.create(out_path)

for(i in 1:length(area_patch)){
    writeRaster(area_patch[[i]]$lsm_p_area,
                paste0(output_path, "/", i, ".tiff")}
```